# setBackgroundResource adds image on top of existing image in Android

Tags: android

I have a timer which is changing the image of an `ImageView` after a certainn amount of time has passed but somehow it's placing a new image on top of the existing one. Why it is not replacing it?

Here is the code which is in my activity class:

```
if(counter.time < (13*40*1000*1)){
     findViewById(R.id.bulbicon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_stage4);
}
else if(counter.time < (13*60*1000)){
     findViewById(R.id.bulbicon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_stage3);
}
else if(counter.time < (14*30*1000)){
     findViewById(R.id.bulbicon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_stage2);
}
```

Here is the layout file which contains the `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bulbicon"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="205dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="248dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.779"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/light_stage1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setBackgroundResource** is for setting the background of an ImageView.

**setImageResource** is for setting the src image of the ImageView.

You need to use **setImageResource** as  per your requirement .
Use this :

```
findViewById(R.id.bulbicon).setImageResource(R.drawable.light_stage3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the background image (from the `View` class) and the source image which you have defined with the `app:srcCompat` attribute (from the `ImageView` class).

You should be using [`ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to change the source.

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with either of the answers then you can accept them with the green tick, which helps future readers find the solution quickly.